# Sending two POST Ajax requests, Server handling them at once

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to send two values to my server to be input into a database in the same row, the problem I have is that it isn't possible to send both values in one request. So what I want to do is send both the values in separate requests but handle them on the server at once so I can add the values into a database as one entry. My php isn't very strong, and I have no idea how to go about doing this. Is it possible? How would I do it?

Here's what I have so far:

```
<?php

$user = "user";
$pass = "pass";
$table = "database";


if(isset($_POST['currentUser']))
{
$userID = 'currentUser';
}

if(isset($_POST ['e.regid']))
{
$regid = 'e.regid';
}


if ($regid && $userID != null)
{
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", $user, $pass);
mysqli_select_db($con, $table);
if (mysqli_connect_errno$con))
{
    echo "Error connecting to the DB: " . mysqli_connect_errno());
}
else
{
    "INSERT INTO gek_devices('regid', 'pin') VALUES ($regid, $userID)";
}
}
```

Comment: You're building an sql string without assigning it anywhere. That means you never actually execute any queries. And even if you were executing it, you'll have syntax errors and be vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: No that is not possible. Also why `the problem I have is that it isn't possible to send both values in one request.` ?

Comment: Marc I'm aware of the vulnerability and would have fixed it before it went live, thank you for mentioning it though.

Answer (score 2):

No, due to network latency and unreliability there's not even any guarantee that both requests will ever arrive at the server, let alone within a minute apart, let alone that you could run code once handling both requests. In practice chances are over 90% that both requests will not even be handled by the same Apache process on the server, given that a default Apache install on *nix will prefork 10 'spare' instances.

If you need to process the data 'simultaneously` you need to send them in the same request, that's the only way to guarantee [atomicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)).

Your intended solution is completely impossible, but also a glaring [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Solve why you can't send the values simultaneously right now instead of focusing on hacky workarounds following that.

Comment: because one of the values is in a plugin that doesn't allow me to inject or call the service which holds the other value to send in the same request. So I am trying to find workarounds.

Comment: I read what the XY problem is, you are completely right about that, if I hadn't have spent 3 days on it I wouldn't be looking for workarounds, if I could just get the plugin to return/call one of the values I need I would be fine. However this is proving to be impossible for me.

Comment: Modify the plugin, or use Javascript's prototyped nature to modify its code at runtime from your own code. You can easily replace functions in an existing object, even if originally defined somewhere else entirely.

Comment: I am trying to call the other value from the plugin, this is the git: https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin if you could tell me how to reference it I would mich appreciate it. I know that's asking quite a lot. Thank you for the help so far.

Comment: Please read the last line of my profile text  ;)   I am active on SO to 'train the brain', to solve puzzles, to help people further with programming. Once it starts to smell like 'work' I have a company with a functional invoicing department.